# Import files directly to SVN repo without checking out first

Tags: svn, bash

I am using SVN and have a repository on a remote machine. Sometimes, when working on my local machine I realize that I need to add some new files to the repo. The usual procedure I know would then be:

1. at the current folder on my local machine checkout the whole SVN repo
2. enter there
3. copy the interesting file here
4. commit

But this can be a bit tedious. I wonder if somehow, I can omit steps 1 to 3 and import the "interesting" file to SVN directly without necessity of checking out the repo first?

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) is what you want ?  Check the documentation for details.

Comment: +1 only thing is he has to do svn import for each file seperately if they are at different locations. Thanks

Comment: Hi HPM, sorry if my explanation was not clear. If I do not checkout repo, how can I import the file to the repo? I tried svn import new_file http:.....repo , but it does not work, it says it does not find svn environemtn variables

Comment: You can pass those environmental variables on the command line, check the usage.  It's probably looking for svn host and port, and username and password.  'svn help import'

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout only the folder where the new files go, add the new files and commit.

Seems to me like what you're doing is dangerous.  If you don't update from SVN first and re-compile the code, you might be introducing bugs or break the build.  Maybe the interface of that class you're using has changed in the repository!

Comment: i work with independent text files, not with a program's source code

Comment: Adding a file to the repository would not break the build...it is a common use case and there is a specific command, `svn import`, to do so.

Comment: In real you can checkout revision 0, add needed file and commit this.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked beautifully for me:

1. Log into Linux machine with the user containing access to the svn repository.
2. Create a new directory e.g. "**cwo_tracking**"  that needs to be added in svn
3. Now just ensure the svn tool is installed and has "import" option in it.
   Run

   > svn import --help
4. Now check the complete HTTPS URL of the SVN directory under which you want to add the new file/folder e.g. **https://SVN_HOST/REPO/PROJECTS/PARENT**. For us it is PARENT which should have "cwo_tracking" folder added after we are done checking in.
5. In your present working directory containing "cwo_tracking" named empty folder, run

   > svn import cwo_tracking https://SVN_HOST/REPO/PROJECTS/PARENT/cwo_tracking
6. This should open a editor to enter comment. Put a relevant comment e.g. "Adding new dir for cwo tracking project", save and exit.
7. Once you save the comment it might ask you for password. If it does, Enter that and If it asks you to save your Password, type no.
8. It should show something like -

   > Committed revision 735.
9. Now open a Web Browser and go to the URL you typed into the import command

   > https://SVN_HOST/REPO/PROJECTS/PARENT/cwo_tracking

That should open a page. This is the one you added!

Comment: (Great post! Note that posts do not need to be addressed to specific individuals, since they are for everyone. If you wish to thank a particular user, upvote the relevant answer).