# How to add an existing folder with files to SVN?

Tags: svn

How do you add a folder without version control to a specific SVN location?  I often start writing code and only after I have a few folders containing code files do I add it to SVN.

What I usually do is:

1. **svn co** the parent directory where I want to make a new folder to store my code.
2. **svn mkdir** to make the directory I want to put my code in.
3. Copy and paste my code over.
4. **svn commit**.
5. Delete my current working code directory.
6. Re-create my working code directory using **svn co**.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431389/import-files-directly-to-svn-repo-without-checking-out-first

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Let's say I have code in the directory `~/local_dir/myNewApp`, and I want to put it under 'https://svn.host/existing_path/myNewApp' (while being able to ignore some binaries, vendor libraries, etc.).

1. Create an empty folder in the repository `svn mkdir https://svn.host/existing_path/myNewApp`
2. Go to the parent directory of the project, `cd ~/local_dir`
3. Check out the empty directory over your local folder. Don't be afraid - the files you have locally will not be deleted. `svn co https://svn.host/existing_path/myNewApp`. If your folder has a different name locally than in the repository, you must specify it as an additional argument.
4. You can see that `svn st` will now show all your files as `?`, which means that they are not currently under revision control
5. Perform `svn add` on files you want to add to the repository, and add others to `svn:ignore`. You may find some useful options with `svn help add`, for example `--parents` or `--depth empty`, when you want selectively add only some files/folders.
6. Commit with `svn ci`

Comment: On point 5 : You can add all files/dirs of your working dir this way in bash :    `find . -name .svn -prune -o -print0|xargs -0 svn add`

Comment: Best how-to I've ever seen for getting new stuff into svn.

Comment: how do you do this: "If your folder has different name locally than in repo, you must specify it as additional argument"

Comment: @KristofPal : `svn co https://svn.host/existing_path/myNewApp ~/local_dir/localNameOfFolder`

Comment: Thank you @qbolec, for, "don't be afraid." +1 on all the, "best answer." As a hint for those who may still be afraid: you may back up your work if you're still afraid.

Comment: What's the point of step 2? You can proceed straight to step 3 in the form `svn co https://svn.host/existing_path/myNewApp .` (note the dot at the end).

Answer (score 55):

If I correctly understood your use case, I suggest to try using **svn add** to put the new folder under version, see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html). The following will add the new folder with files recursively under version control (if you are inside valid working copy):

```
svn add new_folder
svn commit -m "Add New folder to the project"
```

If you are not in a working copy, create it with **svn checkout**, copy new_folder there and do the above steps.

**OR**

Try **svn import**, see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html); the following will create a new folder and upload files to the repository:

```
svn import -m "Import new folder to the project" new_folder \
        http://SVN_REPO/repos/trunk/new_folder
```

Also note that:

> After importing data, note that the original tree is not under version
>   control. To start working, you still need to svn checkout a fresh
>   working copy of the tree

Comment: But the parent folder is not under version control. How does it know where to put it in the svn repository

Comment: It's not clear for me where are your folders then, are you working not in the "working copy"?

Comment: I have an already existing svn repository with folders. I create non svn files and folder and would like to add them to the repository. The  way I do it now is to checkout a directory above where I want to put my project. Then I copy paste to the checkout location and do svn add there.

Comment: @Siecje I think now I understand what you mean

Comment: so I have to do a checkout which means I have to delete the files and redownload them from SVN? So for website files the site would need to go down for a second while I do this?

Comment: @Siecje which files you have to delete, redownload, what is website files - it's not clear from your question/comments, I suggest you to create a new SO question, because here I tried to answer: How do you add a folder without version control to a specific svn location?

Comment: @Siecje BTW I suspect that in your last comment you meant deployment your updated files (on a target webserver running website). I'd suggest to read about SVN hooks, e.g. SVN post-commit server hook (http://imrannazar.com/Automated-Deployment-with-Subversion) - that's completely offtopic here - so, if you need advice - welcome and create new question

Comment: The "OR" part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for.  Didn't want to "co" our entire trunk just to add a new directory below it.  "import" work great for me.  ONE IMPORTANT THING TO NOTE:  You should be in the new directory that you want to add when you run the above import command BECAUSE (at least for me) it took every local file and imported it.  Fortunately <ctrl>-C aborted well, and I was able to correct.

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb I am glad that it helped: btw the syntax is "svn import [PATH] URL", so "it took every local file" because you missed the PATH argument - isnt't that so? Because by default PATH=.

Answer (score 9):

I don't use commands.  You should be able to do this using the GUI:

- Right-click an empty space in your My Documents folder, select TortoiseSVN > Repo-browser.
- Enter http://subversion... (your URL path to your Subversion server/directory you will save to) as your path and select OK
- Right-click the root directory in Repo and select **Add folder**.  Give it the name of your project and create it.
- Right-click the project folder in the Repo-browser and select **Checkout**.  The Checkout directory will be your `Visual Studio\Projects\{your project}` folder.  Select OK.
- You will receive a warning that the folder is not empty.  Say **Yes** to checkout/export to that folder - it will not overwrite your project files.
- Open your project folder.  You will see question marks on folders that are associated with your VS project that have not yet been added to Subversion.  Select those folders using Ctrl + Click, then right-click one of the selected items and select **TortoiseSVN > Add**
- Select OK on the prompt
- Your files should add.  Select OK on the Add Finished! dialog
- Right-click in an empty area of the folder and select Refresh.  You’ll see “+” icons on the folders/files, now
- Right-click an empty area in the folder once again and select **SVN Commit**
- Add a message regarding what you are committing and click OK

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 I did this:

1. Have you installed SVN and Tortoise SVN? If not, Google them and do so now.
2. Go to your SVN folder where you may have other repos (short for repository) (or if you're creating one from scratch, choose a location C drive, D drive, etc or network path).
3. Create a new folder to store your new repository. Call it the same name as your project title
4. Right click the folder and choose Tortoise SVN -> Create Repository here
5. Say yes to Create Folder Structure
6. Click OK. You should see a new icon looking like a "wave" next to your new folder/repo
7. Right Click the new repo and choose SVN Repo Browser
8. Right click 'trunk'
9. Choose ADD Folder... and point to your folder structure of your project in development.
10. Click OK and SVN will ADD your folder structure in. Be patient! It looks like SVN has crashed/frozen. Don't worry. It's doing its work.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is adding the local/working copy to SVN, I used to do it the following way.

Note: I use the [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) client and these steps assume that you already have the TortoiseSVN client installed.

1. I have a project (Test-4.2.2) in my local. I want to upload/add it to an SVN repository.
2. Using the TortoiseSVN repo-browser, I created an empty directory, "Test-4.2.2"
3. In my local I renamed the existing "Test-4.2.2" directory to "Test-4.2.2.1" (temporary)
4. Checkout the empty "Test-4.2.2" from SVN to your local
5. Copy all the sub-directories under 4.2.2.1 to this checkout directory 4.2.2
6. Now, right click "Test-4.2.2" and commit.
7. Delete the temp folder, "Test-4.2.2.1"

Answer (score 1):

3 Steps:

- Open "Repo Browser" (Use Link of yr parent folder) .
- Right click Choose "Add Folder".
- Browse to your folder.

[image]

Comment: You can't add a folder that doesn't exist, this way.  "Add folder" will give you an Explorer window so you can point to an existing folder, then give a commit window so you can add it to Subversion.  It isn't for creating a new folder on the local side - that would still need to be done manually, and populated there, then this could be used for committing its contents to Subversion.  This only gives half of the story.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try.. It is working for me..

```
svn add * --force
```