# How to start using SVN with a project that used SVN in the past

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In the past, my working group used Subversion as version control system to design a concrete software. Unfortunately, for same reasons, the developing of this program was stopped, when it was in version 1.5.6.

Now we'd like to recontinue developing this application, but repositories, .svn folders and every file related to SVN aren't available. We want to follow from version 1.5.6, so how can I create new repository and project which begin updating, commiting... from 1.5.6?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following information is only valid if you have access to the actual source code of the software (a backup, an svn export, a tarball... you get the point)
This way all you'll lose is the commit history of the

- `svnadmin create /path/to/new/svn/repository` (to create a new repository)
- create an empty folder and cd to it
- checkout the repo `svn checkout URL .`
- copy all the projects files into that folder
- `svn add *`
- `svn commit -m "initial commit 1.5.6" --force-log`

alternative way (without a working copy):

(if your source is located at /my/source/location)

- `svnadmin create /path/to/new/svn/repository` (to create a new repository)
- `cd /my/source/location`
- `svn import file:///path/to/new/svn/repository`

The revision number will be 1. Your application should keep its version internally and those two should be separate.

Comment: now I see it seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510119/how-to-add-an-existing-folder-with-files-to-svn