# Sharing existing folders to multiple locations in the repository

Tags: wordpress, svn, plugins

I am developing several WordPress websites that each use several plugins that I am also developing. I want to be able to update the plugins within any of the websites and have the updates show up in the other websites. I am also using Tortoise SVN as the client.

What is the best way to keep *one* copy of an existing plugin's folder in the repository, which gets used on multiple websites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an existing folder with files to SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510119/how-to-add-an-existing-folder-with-files-to-svn)

Comment: Let me reframe the question: Projects A and B each contain copies of folder F. Any update to the contents of A-->F should, upon updating B, appear in B-->F. How do I configure A.F and B.F to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).

Assume as per your comment on your question that you have two projects A and B, with shared plugin F.

Place the shared plugin F into its own folder within your repository separate from both A and B. For example, it could go in `{repository root}/Plugins/F/trunk`.

On some folder in both A and B, then, you can create a special property called `svn:externals` that contains a pointer to F, and a location to place F inside the working copy for the project. For example, you could have an `svn:externals` definition on an A/trunk/plugins folder as follows:

```
^/Plugins/F/trunk@123 F
```

When you check out or update your working copy for project A, SVN will now automatically create a new working copy for plugin F, in A/trunk/plugins. Note my use of `@123` in the above. This means that this new working copy for plugin F will be pulled from revision 123. You *can* leave off this revision specifier[1], but you *shouldn't*. If you do leave off the revision specifier, then you can simply `svn update` each project after making changes to F, and see those changes show up immediately. However, you then make it very difficult to reconstruct past versions of the project, because even updating to an old version of the project, will always pull in the *latest* version of the plugin. Additionally, if you make an incompatible change to the plugin, you will break every other project when you update them. By putting in the revision specifier, you can make a conscious decision of when is a good time to pull in the latest version of the plugin.

[1] This is technically called a "peg revision", and a revision specifier is slightly different, but you don't typically need to care about this detail in svn:externals definitions.