# How to add a new maven project to SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to SVN. Can some one help me on, How to add a new maven project, which is on my local machine to SVN. step by step

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was already asked here in SO:

[How to add an existing folder with files to SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511432/3501205)

You will need to:

1. `checkout` from the repository you want to commit (You have to know the URI of this repository).
2. Place the Maven project in the folder you just checked out.
3. `add` all the files you want to commit.
4. `commit` to SVN.